# Can I rescind the choice to share data about my iTunes library contents with Apple?

Tags: itunes, sharing

I installed the new iTunes 11 on my Mac and I accepted to share my iTunes library with Apple. There were some initial welcome screens and I opeted in when I started the new version of iTunes the first time.

How can I cancel this sharing of data with Apple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iTunes, you can opt back out of sharing details by opening the preferences and selecting the store preferences tab.

[image: iTunes store preference]